# PassportJS events.js:160 //Unhandled 'error' connection timeout

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, mongoose, passport.js

I'm creating a MEAN Stack app and recently I included passportjs, at first when my Mongo Database was 1GB (it has over 3 million entries) everything was fine, but recently the database grew to up to 2GB and when passport is called 1/3 times it throws this error on console:

```
(calling passport)
POST /login 200 3600.661 ms - 492 // successful login
GET /uploads/defaultm4.jpg 304 1.295 ms - -
(calling passport)
POST /login 200 3334.007 ms - 492 // successful login
(calling passport)
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connection timeout
    at Db.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\bootcamp\voting-app\node_modules\m                                                                                                                ongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:169:17)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Db.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Server.listener (C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\bootcamp\voting-app\node_modules\                                                                                                                mongodb\lib\db.js:1786:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\bootcamp\voting-app\node_modul                                                                                                                es\mongodb\lib\server.js:274:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\bootcamp\voting-app\node_modules                                                                                                                \mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:334:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\bootcamp\voting-app\node_m                                                                                                                odules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:270:12)
    at Connection.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\bootcamp\voting-app\node_modul                                                                                                                es\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:183:10)
    at Socket.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:339:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Andre\\AppData\\                                                                                                                Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! votingApp@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the votingApp@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the votingApp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs votingApp
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls votingApp
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\bootcamp\voting-app\npm-debug.log
```

This is my App.js:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var session = require('express-session')
    var http = require('http');
    var path = require('path');
    var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var app = express();

    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var passport = require('passport');

    var options = {server: {socketOptions: {connectionTimeoutMS: 120000,socketTimeoutMS: 120000}}};


    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mean-database',options, function(err,db){
        if (!err){
            console.log('Connected to /mean-database!');
        } else{
            console.dir(err); //failed to connect
        }
    });  


    require('./models/citizens');
    require('./config/passport');
    require('./models/Candidate');
    require('./models/Province');
    require('./models/Parties');

    var routes = require('./routes/index');

    var citizens = require('./routes/citizens');
    var candidates = require('./routes/candidates');
    var provinces = require('./routes/provinces');
    var graphics = require('./routes/graphics');
    var parties = require('./routes/parties');
    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));

    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(passport.initialize());



    app.use('/', routes);
    app.use('/users', citizens);
    app.use('/api', candidates);
    app.use('/api', provinces);
    app.use('/api', graphics);
    app.use('/api', citizens);
    app.use('/api', parties);
    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        var err = new Error('Not Found');
        err.status = 404;
        next(err);
    });

    // error handlers

    // development error handler
    // will print stacktrace
    if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
        app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
            res.status(err.status || 500);
            res.render('error', {
                message: err.message,
                error: err
            });
        });
    }

    // production error handler
    // no stacktraces leaked to user
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: {}
        });
    });


    module.exports = app;
```

This is my "start" script:

```
var debug = require('debug')('votingApp');
var app = require('../app');


app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

And this is my passport.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('Citizen');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(electoral_code, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ electoral_code: electoral_code }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    }).maxTime(20000);
  }
));
```

I already tried: reinstalling node, updating all node modules, cleaning cache, reinstalling all modules

**EDIT:** also adding npm-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Andre\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.9.0
3 info using node@v6.9.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle votingApp@0.0.0~prestart: votingApp@0.0.0
6 silly lifecycle votingApp@0.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle votingApp@0.0.0~start: votingApp@0.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle votingApp@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle votingApp@0.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\bootcamp\voting-app\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\Andre\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Andre\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
10 verbose lifecycle votingApp@0.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\bootcamp\voting-app
11 silly lifecycle votingApp@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node ./bin/www' ]
12 silly lifecycle votingApp@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle votingApp@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: votingApp@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:245:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Andre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid votingApp@0.0.0
16 verbose cwd C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\bootcamp\voting-app
17 error Windows_NT 10.0.14393
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Andre\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
19 error node v6.9.2
20 error npm  v3.9.0
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error votingApp@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the votingApp@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the votingApp package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     node ./bin/www
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs votingApp
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls votingApp
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I solved this issue by indexing the Mongo Database:

```
db.citizens.ensureIndex({ username: 1, password: 1 })
```